# Two numbers are chosen independently and at random.

Tags: probability

Two numbers are chosen independently and at random from 
set { 1,2.....13}. Find The probability that theor 4-bit unsigned 
binary representatives have the same most significant 
bit .

note: unsigned is way of representation of +ve numbers. I am giving the binary representation of unsigned 4 bit binary numbers from 0 -15.

0000
0001
0010
0011
0100
0101
0110
0111
1000
1001
1010
1011
1100
1101
1110
1111

Comment: How did you get 6/13? @maveric

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  how many have MSB of $0$?  How many have MSB of $1$?  How many ways to choose two that have the same MSB?  The answer depends on whether the choice is with or without replacement, which you did not specify.

Added:  there are seven numbers with MSB of $0$ and six with MSB of $1$.  There are ${7 \choose 2}+{6 \choose 2}=21+15=36$ ways to choose two numbers with the same MSB.  There are ${13 \choose 2}=78$ ways to choose two numbers overall, so the probability is $\frac {36}{78}=\frac {18}{39}$

Comment: without replacement. i am getting 6/13 ans is 1/2

Comment: @maveric without replacement, use $n^2$ instead of $\binom n2$ in all the above calculations , since $n^2$ is the count of ways to make 2 independent selections each from $n$ options..

Answer (score 0):

There are 7 numbers which are having the same MSB(0).

There are 6 numbers which are having the same MSB(1).

so the probability will be = $(\frac{7} {13} \times \frac{7} { 13}) + (\frac{6} { 13} \times \frac{6} {13})$
                           = $\frac{85} { 169}$
                           = $0.50295$